# Get domain name with NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'd like to get the domaine name using NodeJS.

My code : `request.headers.host`

It returns `127.0.0.1:3007` instead of `http://domainname.fr`...

**Edit #1 :**

```
{"host":"127.0.0.1:3007","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36","referer":"http://domainname.fr/option/seo/edit","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.8,ca;q=0.6,de;q=0.4,es;q=0.2,fil;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2,it;q=0.2,pt;q=0.2","cookie":"wp-settings-1=libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26post_dfw%3Doff%26hidetb%3D1%26editor%3Dtinymce; wp-settings-time-1=1453197454; _ga=GA1.2.1880128487.1451319866; connect.sid=s%3A6rtTBduaUul9Q0o_p7vxF6TzmMcfQs19.kaBdkoGAeQtQuxHsfwDsEscbOYFsZpnTIlluk2u0X0Q","x-forwarded-for":"86.207.238.8","x-forwarded-host":"domainname.fr","x-forwarded-server":"domainname.fr","connection":"Keep-Alive"}
```

Comment: please check what data you are getting by adding console.log(JSON.stringify(request.headers));

Comment: Isn't there a nginx or apache as a proxy?

Comment: Yes I'm using Express, see edit #1 with `console.log(JSON.stringify(request.headers));`

Comment: your using some web proxy try    request.headers["x-forwarded-host"]

Comment: Have you tried `require("os").hostname()`?

Comment: With `request.headers["x-forwarded-host"]` I get that `Possibly unhandled NoURLProtocolError. Protocol is required` and with `require("os").hostname()` I get the same error message...

Comment: I have to ask...are you making the request from the same machine?

Comment: Shouldn't you already know what domain you used for your site ?

Comment: Yes that's from the same machine ^^. No the domain name is private. But I found a solution like WordPress or Prestashop, now I just need to specify in my back-office the domaine name.

Comment: Of course he already knows the domain name of his site. He's asking the question because his site's CODE needs to know the domain name. Come on, people.

Answer (score 0):

Under the req.headers you can check for "origin" or  "referer".
Also, if you search for the initiator, you can find it under "from".